# Vulnerability NTP:Traffic amplification in clrtrap feature of ntpd affect or not affect to Cisco device?

Tags: audit, security-theater, dnssec, mod-security, content-security-policy

I am using CCSVM tool SCAN for Network devices (Cisco). Below you can find the scan result:

> Title vulnerability: NTP: Traffic amplification in clrtrap feature of
>   ntpd Solution fix: Disable NTP queries Apply a restrict option to all
>   hosts that are not authorized to perform NTP queries. For example, to
>   deny query requests from all clients, put the following in the NTP
>   configuration file, typically /etc/ntp.conf, and restart the NTP
>   service:
>          restrict -4 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
>          restrict -6 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap

Please help check this vulnerability on Cisco Network devices. Are they affected or not affected? What should be the solution if these are vulnerable?